# Why strcasecmp return true with array and string?

Tags: php

```
if(!strcasecmp(array(), "abc"))
{
     echo "ok";
}
```

Why strcasecmp return true with array and string?

Comment: your code isn't okay, `strcasecmp` takes two strings as parameters!
see : https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php

Comment: This is not a question really that we like to see on SO. The first thing you should always do is check out the manual. It takes less time to look it up than to write a post.
If you still have questions then look for duplicates - maybe someone has a similar problem. If not, then you might post it here.

Comment: You can check that the code work . And because I have already checked the manual and it is not written on it and I was looking for if someone asked something similar but did not find any. so I ask if anyone know why.

Answer (score 1):

`strcasecmp()` requires the arguments to be strings. If either argument isn't a string, it returns `NULL`. `NULL` is falsey, so `!strcasecmp(array(), "abc")` returns `TRUE`.

Comment: but I use ! so any positive number return false.

Comment: You asked what `strcasecmp()` returns, not what `!strcasecmp()` returns.

Answer (score 0):

If you have error reporting enabled like so...

```
<?php
// Enable FULL Error Reporting on the screen
// ONLY USE IN DEVELOPMENT
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

if(!strcasecmp(array(), "abc"))
{
    echo "ok";
}
```

You will get...

> Warning: strcasecmp() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in
> home/phptutorials/public_html/index.php on line 7
>
> ok